# Codeigniter changed md5 on bcrpt hashed password

Tags: php, codeigniter, md5, bcrypt

How change in CodeIgniter md5 on the bcrypt? I would like to hashed password

Model Code http://wklej.org/id/2784670/

```
public function can_log_in($login, $password){

    // var_dump($login);
    // print_r($password);
    // bcrypt
    //  die;
    // print_r(md5($password));

    $result = $this->db
              ->from('users')
              ->where('email', $login)
              ->where('password', md5($password))
              ->get();

    // print_r($result);die;

    $this->db->where('email', $login);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($password));  How change md5 on bcrypt?>???!

    $query = $this->db->get('users');


    if ($result->num_rows()== 1){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: you should visit this first
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Krystian Niko Liris I have dded a answer hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can change into bcrpt hashed passowrd through it

$this->hashpassword($this->input->post('password'))

Comment: I would like to function reset password have you clever?

Answer (score 1):

> I would use php [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-examples)

On your database password column `varchar 255`

```
public function createUser() {
    $options = [
       'cost' => 12,
    ];

    $new_password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

    $data = array(
       'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
       'password' => $new_password
    );

    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->insert('user');
}
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
$2y$12$QjSH496pcT5CEbzjD/vtVeH03tfHKFy36d4J0Ltp3lRtee9HDxY3K
```

> And php [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php#refsect1-function.password-verify-examples)

Then what you need to do is

Model [Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#what-is-a-model)

Filename: Login_model.php

```
<?php

class Login_model extends CI_Model {

    public function getUser() {
        if ($this->verify()) {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('user');
            $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $query->row();
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    public function verify() {
        $hashed = $this->getHash();
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        if (password_verify($password, $hashed)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getHash() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row()->password;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller [Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world)

Filename: Login.php

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = 'Login';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_verify');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

            $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer_view', $data);

        } else {

            $userdata = $this->login_model->getUser();

            $data = array(
                'user_id' => $userdata->user_id
            );

            // You can set your session userdata

            redirect('success');
        }
    }

    public function verify() {
        if ($this->login_model->verify()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('verify', 'Opps something gone wrong!');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Don't for get to set your base_url in config.php as required to do so in CI3 versions